# How to use an angular component inside a form group?

Tags: angular, forms

I am currently learning Angular and having been trying to build forms.

Currently the two inputs in my form belong to a FormGroup:

```
    <form name="myForm" #form>
       <input name="username" />
       <input name="email" />
    </form>
```

I am trying to make the email input its own component like this:

```
    <form name="myForm" #form>
       <input name="username" />
       <email-input name="email" />
    </form>
```

email-input component:

```
    <div>
      <input />
    </div>
```

When I add the email-input component to the form, it is not part of the FormGroup like before, my question is without changing how I implement my form, how can I add my email-input component to the #form FormGroup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.addProductForm = this.fb.group({
      prodCtrl: [''],
      colors: new FormArray([]),
      prodFilterCtrl: [''],
      actual_price: ['']
    });
```

```
<form [formGroup]="addProductForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
      <button [mat-dialog-close]="true" mat-raised-button color="primary"
      [disabled]="SaveButtonDisable" (click)="addProduct()" class="save-button">{{'SAVE_BTN' | translate:lang }}</button>
      <button [mat-dialog-close]="true" mat-raised-button color="secondary">{{'BACK_BTN' | translate:lang}}</button>
    </div>
    <!--  [disabled]="productSelect.empty" -->
  </div>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="common-prod-form-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select required [formControl]="prodCtrl" placeholder="Select" #productSelect  (selectionChange)="onChangeProduct($event.value)">
            <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="prodFilterCtrl" placeholderLabel="Find product..."  ></ngx-mat-select-search>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts | async" [value]="product">
              {{product.product_name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>
    

</form>
```

Comment: How does this solution address the asker's question?

Comment: Yes @Edric you can use [formGroup]="addProductForm"  inside [formControl]="prodCtrl"
in your case 
  <form name="myForm" #form>
       <input   [formControl]="username"  name="username" />
       <email-input [formControl]="email" name="email" />
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parent formGroup to child component

Try this tutorial

https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664